# corporate intranet portal with drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am new to drupal. I need to develop a **corporate intranet portal** using drupal 7.
I have features like,

- Employee profile creation
- Announcement (Internal announcement, internal opportunities, display
  new joiners with their      photo and info)
- Employee birthday celebration
- Awards
- Discussion board
- Survey
- LMS
- Event calendar

  and many more.

I would like to know whether corporate portal can be built with drupal.
Please let me know if there any modules for the above requirement or any opensource for this .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know whether corporate portal can be built with
>   drupal.

Yes it is possible.

> Please let me know if there any modules for the above requirement or
>   any opensource for this.

The question cannot be answered properly without knowing the exact requirements and then digging very deep. The result would be mostly writing a book.

To be honest as you are new to drupal and the way your question "sounds" to me" you are likely to fail with the project. Therefore I would recommend you check out how far [open atrium](http://openatrium.com/) (Drupal 6) or other [install profiles](https://drupal.org/project/installation+profiles) / [distributions](https://drupal.org/documentation/build/distributions) meet your requirements and try to sell one of these (plus customization) to your client. Or at least first look how the authors of open atrium, Drupal Commons and [others](http://drupaldistrowatch.com/drupal_distributions) do things and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a very general question, I can give you a general answer only.

Drupal has a lot of solid features built into core which will help you to build this portal. Probably the most important one is fields and its contrib friend [views](http://drupal.org/project/views). There's also a good forum with a number of add on modules which are helpfull to you. The [calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) and [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) modules are very powerfull and flexible to do any date related stuff.

Depending on how flexible you are in just doing things the Drupal way vs. customizing things to your specific needs you have to be prepared to just find the right modules and may write some glue code or do serious custom module and theme developement. Hiring a Drupal pro to sort this out can save you a lot of trial and failure in the long run.